# Is there a variable that references the path to the Maven settings xml within the pom file?

Tags: java, maven, variables, pom.xml, maven-settings

In my pom file I need to launch another Maven command via the `org.codehaus.mojo.exec-maven-plugin` plugin by passing it the Maven settings file: Is there a variable that references the path to the Maven settings xml within the pom file?

Here the code I'm using (I need to replace the variable `${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}` which is a manually set environment variable):

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-my-app</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <JAVA_HOME>${java.home}</JAVA_HOME>
                                <M2_HOME>${maven.home}</M2_HOME>
                            </environmentVariables>
                            <executable>${maven.home}/bin/mvn</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--settings</argument>
                                <argument>${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}</argument>
                                <argument>clean</argument>
                                <argument>package</argument>
                                <argument>-f</argument>
                                <argument>${PARENT_PROJECT_ABSOLUTE_PATH}\pom.xml</argument>
                                <argument>-Dhttps.protocols=${https.protocols}</argument>
                                <argument>-X</argument>
                                <argument>-U</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

... And this is the log from my building:

```bash
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from F:\Shared\Programs\Apache\Maven\3.2.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from F:\Shared\Data\Programs\Apache\Maven\my-project-custom-settings.xml
```

I need to retrieve the second one location in my `pom.xml`

Comment: Since Maven is a external tool which is either bundled in JVM or is supposed to reside on the machine where code is executing, I feel it should only be used as a environment variable rather than referencing it through a value in POM file, since POM files are part of the build files that are created, shipped and deployed.

Comment: Beyond the technical choice, is there or not a native variable in the pom file that references the location of the current Maven settings xml?

Comment: Wouldn't it already be too late for that? Maven would already be invoked with a location for settings *in order to process your pom*

Comment: No, because I need to pass the current settings file to the second maven command: I am currently invoking the first maven command using the `${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}` variable

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The (only) way to change the settings file location is to use the `-s` command line switch to `mvn`. Once that either has or has not been done, the settings file location has been decided *before any pom is read*

Comment: I don't want to change the location of the settings file: I want to get the location of the current settings file and pass it to the second Maven command invoked via the `org.codehaus.mojo.exec-maven-plugin` plugin

Comment: Why would you need to? The location of the current settings file would be known to Maven

Comment: Sorry, I feel like we're going out of context with all these questions, but do you know the solution to the question I'm asking or not?

Comment: Personally I think we've got an XY problem here. It would be [better to state your goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)

Comment: @PeterH Why do you need to launch a `mvn clean package` from within the POM with the exec plugin?

Comment: @g00se The problem is really very simple: how to get the path of the current settings file within the pom file? Is there an internal maven variable that contains this value like the variable that references the pom file `${project.pomFile.absolutePath}`?

Comment: The real question is why do you like to run Maven from within Maven (via exec-maven-plugin)? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Apart from the the version is extremely Old (version 1.1?)

Comment: @JFabianMeier I'm launching, in my pom, another maven command with an external pom: 
please don't make me explain the reason for all this because it is truly a complex situation that concerns a very old project that my company assigned to me for work

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm launching, in my pom, another maven command with an external pom: please don't make me explain the reason for all this because it is truly a complex situation that concerns a very old project that my company assigned to me for work

Comment: *@g00se The problem is really very simple: how to get the path of the current settings file within the pom file?* Please read the link I posted. *Even if* this was a legitimate thing to be doing, I've already said it's unnecessary as that is *already known* to Maven. A *different* settings location is another matter, but you've already said it isn't different

Comment: We are going out of context, I repeat the question: how to get the path of the current settings file within the pom file? Is there an internal maven variable that contains this value like the variable that references the pom file `${project.pomFile.absolutePath}`?

Comment: You're not reading the comment answers. The settings *are already known* to Maven and are system: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml and, user: ~/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: @g00se the maven settings I'm using is located outside the maven home and I set it with the `--settings` parameter: if I remove the         `<argument>--settings</argument>
        <argument>${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}</argument>` it doesn't work

Comment: You're confusing me as you said *I don't want to change the location of the settings file:*, so it seems you do and *have* done. That won't work for the reason I gave you. You could probably execute a script *from Maven* invoking Maven with a changed settings file location

Comment: I need to get the path to the settings xml passed via the `--settings` parameter and pass this location to the `org.codehaus.mojo.exec-maven-plugin plugin`: I noticed that the value of this parameter corresponds to the user settings. I was hoping there was some variable like `${user.settingsFile.absolutePath}`

Comment: @g00se I think you actually misunderstood the question. The OP wants to start a completely unrelated Maven run from within the POM and therefore wants the location of the settings.xml as it was given (or not given) by the Maven command line.

Comment: @PeterH I think, you might be able to find some property like `${settings.settingsXml}` or something similar. The thing is: I am pretty sure, if you would explain the "truly complex situation" you are in, that we would find a better, more fitting solution for it.

Comment: *@g00se I think you actually misunderstood the question. The OP wants to start a completely unrelated Maven run from within the POM* Nope ;) Not only did I understand it but I gave a solution involving scripting.

Comment: @g00se The OP wants to start Maven with a certain settings.xml and then start another Maven run from within the first with the very same settings.xml

Comment: @JFabianMeier exactly!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to have a parent project with modules in maven?

Comment: @cyberbrain I should explain to you many architectural details of an old and poorly implemented project: I'll just tell you that the second pom calls an ant task to run the build. The solution I found works now, but I wanted to make it more flexible by changing the Maven settings reference in the main pom as requested

Comment: I don't see how that would limit a module setup. And for the ant task: you know about the antrun maven plugin? Just asking because you use the exec-maven-plugin in this question.

Comment: @cyberbrain Obviously I use them: but this way we get out of context: tell me if you know a variable that references to the path of the maven user settings file, because the project build is working, but I just wanted to make it more flexible.

Comment: @PeterH See: With the question as it is, it is unlikely that you get an answer. If you would take 10 minutes of your time to explain the architecture, we might find a much better solution for your problem. I have seen hundreds of Maven projects.

Comment: This is the log from my building: `[DEBUG] Reading global settings from F:\Shared\Programs\Apache\Maven\3.2.5\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading user settings from F:\Shared\Data\Programs\Apache\Maven\my-project-custom-settings.xml`
I need to retrieve the second one location in my pom.xml

Comment: There is no such property. It's a *parameter* to `mvn` else default. You could write a script to insert both into the right place

Comment: @PeterH I cannot understand why you don't want to find a proper solution instead of your ugly hack. But I can only help you if you write down the details of your architecture.

Answer (score -1):

There cannot be a single property to point you to "the settings file" because Maven uses multiple files together to calculate it's settings:

> The Maven install: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
> A user's install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

(from the [Maven Settings Reference, Quick Overview](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#quick-overview))

Also from there:

> If both files exists, their contents gets merged,...

And several settings from those files could also be configured project specific within the current *pom.xml* file or one of the projects ancestors (parent, parents parent, etc.).

What you could try: to use the [maven-help-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/index.html) with its goal [help:effective-settings](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html) in your project to create a new settings file that you then pass on to your executed JVM.

All of this looks so overly complicated and error-prone to me that I would rather advise to refactor the project setup to create a proper aggregation (multi-module) project as described in Mavens [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#aggregation-or-multi-module).

Comment: This is the log from my building:
`[DEBUG] Reading global settings from F:\Shared\Programs\Apache\Maven\3.2.5\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading user settings from F:\Shared\Data\Programs\Apache\Maven\my-project-custom-settings.xml`
I need to retrieve the second one location in my `pom.xml`

Comment: no, you need both, because somebody could override the global settings with the commandline parameter `-gs` or `--global-settings`

Comment: @cyberbrain While this is theoretically possible, this is usually not done.

Comment: @JFabianMeier the whole scenario from the question "is usually not done".